# Исключить пересечение из подсчёта

Tags: sql, sql-server

Посмотрим на такой запрос: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/794665/982860/angular-react-vue

```
select
  cast(floor(cast(p.creationDate as float) / 30) * 30 as datetime),

  --sum(iif(t.TagName = N'reactjs', 1, 0)) as [react],
  --sum(iif(t.TagName = N'angular', 1, 0)) as [a2+],
  --sum(iif(t.TagName in (N'vue.js', N'vuejs2'), 1, 0)) as [vue],
  --sum(iif(t.TagName = N'angularjs', 1, 0)) as [ang.js],

  round(sum(iif(t.TagName = N'reactjs', 1, 0)) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) as [react %],
  round(sum(iif(t.TagName = N'angular', 1, 0)) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) as [a2+ %],
  round(sum(iif(t.TagName in (N'vue.js', N'vuejs2'), 1, 0)) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) as [vue %],
  round(sum(iif(t.TagName = N'angularjs', 1, 0)) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) as [ang.js %],

  --count(distinct p.Id) as [questions],
  --count(*) as [total],
  round(count(distinct p.Id) * 100.0 / count(*), 1) as [accuracy %]
from
  Posts p
  inner join PostTags pt on p.Id = pt.PostId
  inner join Tags t on pt.TagID = t.Id
where
  t.TagName in (N'reactjs', N'angular', N'angularjs', N'vue.js', N'vuejs2')
  and p.PostTypeId = 1
group by
  cast(floor(cast(p.creationDate as float) / 30) * 30 as datetime)
order by
  1 desc
```

Тут вопросы (`Posts p`, `p.PostTypeId = 1`) джойнятся с метками, группируются по 30 дней и выбираются те, которые содержат интересующие метки.

```
t.TagName in (N'reactjs', N'angular', N'angularjs', N'vue.js', N'vuejs2')
```

Затем метки делятся на 4 поднабора и по каждому из них считается число строк, содержащих эту метку. Проблема в том, что вместо числа **вопросов** считается число **строк**. Дело в том, что на одном вопросе может быть несколько меток. Например, рассмотрим такую ситуацию: есть 5 вопросов с 9 метками

```
Q1   reactjs
Q2   vue.js reactjs
Q3   vue.js vuejs2
Q4   angularjs
Q5   angular reactjs angularjs
```

Т. е. есть:

- 3 вопроса с меткой `reactjs`
- 2 вопроса с меткой `vue.js` или `vuejs2`
- 2 вопроса с меткой `angularjs`
- 1 вопрос с меткой `angular`

желаемый результат один из следующих:

```
react       vue         angularjs   angular
3/5=60.0%   2/5=40.0%   2/5=40.0%   1/5=20.0%
3/8=37.5%   2/8=25.0%   1/8=12.5%   1/8=12.5%
```

Первый вариант выражает *число вопросов с подходящей меткой*, а второй - *долю использования группы меток по отношению к другим* - именно группы, а не метки, поэтому идёт деление на 8, а не на 9.

однако, после join получится нечто другое:

```
Q1   reactjs
Q2   vue.js
Q2   reactjs
Q3   vue.js
Q3   vuejs2
Q4   angularjs
Q5   angular
Q5   reactjs
Q5   angularjs
```

соответственно формула даст

```
react       vue         angularjs   angular
3/5=60.0%   3/5=60.0%   2/5=40.0%   1/5=20.0%
3/9=33.3%   3/9=33.3%   2/9=22.2%   1/9=11.1%
```

Проблема заключается в том, что две записи

```
Q3   vue.js
Q3   vuejs2
```

были посчитаны независимо, хотя они относятся к одному вопросу и к одной группе меток.

**Как переделать sql запрос таким образом, чтобы подобные совпадения исключались из подсчёта? Причём, сделать таким образом, чтобы каждая группа могла содержать более одного тега?**

Comment: Вместо `sum()` попробуйте `count(distinct iif(t.TagName in (N'vue.js', N'vuejs2'), p.id, NULL))`, мне кажется поможет, если я правильно понял вопрос и то что p.id это как раз id вопроса.

Comment: @Mike, да, должно получиться. А чего не ответом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как нам надо посчитать некие уникальные значения (например id постов), то использовать для этого надо `count(distinct)`, вместо `sum()`. Для него надо эти самые уникальные значения создать. Для любого из постов в одной группе выдадим id поста в качестве этого значения (или NULL если тег не совпал). Для подсчета общего количества разных групп тегов в строках нам так же не подойдет обычный `count(*)`, возьмем в качестве уникального значения id поста и некое обозначение группы тегов, например приведя все теги одной группы к одному из названий.

Итого выражение для подсчета выходит:

```
  round( count(distinct iif(t.TagName in (N'vue.js', N'vuejs2'), p.id, NULL)) * 100.0 / 
         count(distinct iif(t.TagName='vuejs2','vue.js',t.TagName)+cast(p.id as varchar)),
         1) as [vue %]
```

Итоговый запрос на [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/795114/angular-react-vue)

Comment: С числителем ясно, а в знаменателе что? А, понял. Конкатенация эталонной метки с id даёт группу.